# Too many threads running

Tags: java, multithreading

In our AppServer we are seeing threadcount exceeding its JMX thread count threshold (Max = 500, Actual = 595).

I see there are no deadlocks. I have taken a thread dump and see that out of the 595 threads, majority of them fall in 2 categories:

1) 234 threads in Timed Waiting (Thread Dump shown below)

```
"Timer-232" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f46c85cd000 nid=0x7b06 in Object.wait() [0x00007f4668001000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x000000075246c498> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)
        - locked <0x000000075246c498> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

2) 233 threads in Waiting state (Thread Dump shown below). I guess this is the culprit being blocked on a queue, specifically Delay queue.

```
"AsyncHttpClient-Reaper" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f469cd4c000 nid=0x7b09 waiting on condition [0x00007f4667cfe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000007524a2908> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
        at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:160)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:609)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can you please help me understand what is causing the threads to exceed JMX threshold? Its the first time I am working with thread scenario and hence unable to come to a solid analysis. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're running long jobs in your threads and firing more and more jobs.

Comment: The answer is simple: You are creating too many threads. Sounds obvious but it actually is the case. Way to analyse could be to log whenever you start a new thread and see what is causing the most threads. Or check if you can find out what these threads are doing and why they aren't finishing...

Comment: As Stuart suggested, and if you can do it, learn the Java `Executors` and `ThreadPool` concept and rewrite those parts of the application.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi, Warren and Watery for your insights into this. One strange thing I see is that it happens in only one server. We have our application on 8 servers. But why this is happening in only one server. We have same -xmx and -xms for java across all servers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are thrashing your system with too many async requests. Throttle them or set a max pool count for these requests

Comment: Thanks Coffee for your insights into this. One strange thing I see is that it happens in only one server. We have our application on 8 servers. But why this is happening in only one server. We have same -xmx and -xms for java across all servers.

Comment: It's hard to say with what we know so far. It could be server affinity, poor load balancing (if they are on the same environment), networking quirks, different hardware/vm specs, etc. A couple things I would start looking into is taking a look at how many requests that one app server is receiving compared to the other servers as well as a look at CPU usage. Maybe test response times on that server compared to the others to see if you are seeing slower response times. Basically any sign to suggest something is going on in that server that's not occurring on the others

Answer (score 2):

Half of your threads are instances of `java.util.TimerThread`. An instance of this thread is created whenever something creates an instance of `java.util.Timer`; every `Timer` instance creates its own thread.

It looks like the timer thread is in a state where it's waiting for a specific time period to elapse before executing a `TimerTask`. Since there are so many timer threads, it may be that there is some place in the code that is creating new `Timer` instances each time it wants to schedule a `TimerTask`. This will end up creating as many threads as there are pending tasks, which is potentially quite wasteful.

If the tasks to be run are short-lived and are reliable, they can all share a single `Timer` instance.

However, if a task is long-running, it may delay the execution of subsequent tasks. Or if the task throws an uncaught exception, it will take down the timer thread and prevent subsequent tasks from being executed at all. If either of these is a possibility, you should use `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` to create a single `ScheduledExecutorService` and schedule tasks on it instead of creating new `Timer` instances.

Comment: Thanks Stuart for your insights into this. One strange thing I see is that it happens in only one server. We have our application on 8 servers. But why this is happening in only one server. We have same -xmx and -xms for java across all servers.